# Visual Studio 2019 designer, setting an array property in designer causes popup "Property value not valid"

Tags: c#, user-controls, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019, version 16.8.2
I have a .net Core 5 user library.  To diagnose a problem in an existing project converted to Core 5, I have created a simple user control:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsControlLibrary2
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        private TwoElems[] mynums = { new TwoElems(), new TwoElems() };
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        [Browsable(true), NotifyParentProperty(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Category("Log control parameters")]
        [DisplayName("array property")]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public TwoElems[] MyNums
        {
            get { return mynums; }
            set { mynums = value; }
        }
    }
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public class TwoElems
    {
        [Browsable(true), NotifyParentProperty(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        public int sz { get; set; }
        public TwoElems()
        {
            sz = 30;
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles fine and the project containing this user control is added to the toolbox.
Then the control is added to a form, and clicking the ellipses (...) to open the sub-property page for MyNums, the items are shown.

Changing the value of either item causes a popup in the property sheet saying:
Property value is not valid
and the Detail being:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Clicking on OK to dismiss the popup and re-examining the array property show that the changed values ***are*** written back to property.

This sort of code (array properties) worked fine under the .net framework and/or earlier version of Visual Studio.

Any ideas on how to determine what is causing this?

Regards, Oz

Comment: Cause the issue only occurs under .NET5, you can report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=61).

Comment: Thank you Kyle for the link.  I have reported this.